# How to use multi-vector types in ARM64 inline assembly?

Tags: simd, inline-assembly, arm64

In ARM64 compilers with GCC-like `__asm__`, how could I make use of multi-vector NEON types like `uint8x16x4_t`?

```c
uint8x16x4_t Meow()
{
    uint8x16x4_t result;
    __asm__(
        "meow %0"
    :   "=w"(result));
    return result;
}
```

That results in the following assembly output:

```
    meow v0
```

Is there a way to get it to be something like this?:

```
    meow { v0.16b - v3.16b }
```

Or even better, refer to the individual parts somehow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have to do it manually, but you can do so with the `T`, `U` and `V` modifiers. And suffixes can just be specified literally. The following code:

```c
uint8x16x4_t Meow()
{
    uint8x16x4_t result;
    __asm__(
        "meow { %0.16b, %T0.16b, %U0.16b, %V0.16b }"
    :   "=w"(result));
    return result;
}
```

gives me:

```
Meow:
    meow { v4.16b, v5.16b, v6.16b, v7.16b }
    mov     v1.16b, v5.16b
    mov     v2.16b, v6.16b
    mov     v3.16b, v7.16b
    mov     v0.16b, v4.16b
    ret
```

Comment: Additionally, you might want to consider using [intrinsics](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/ARM-C-Language-Extensions-_0028ACLE_0029.html).  Generally a much better solution than [mucking about with inline asm](https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/DontUseInlineAsm).

Comment: @DavidWohlferd GCC didn't add `vld1q_u8_x4` until GCC 10, which we aren't using yet. That's what prompted me to use inline assembly for the multi-vector loads in the first place. The rest of the code in the .cpp file uses NEON intrinsics =^-^=

Comment: Fair enough.  Some people get so wrapped up in how sexy inline asm is that they miss the alternatives, so I thought I'd mention.